# Cross Domain access to USPS API

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a CORS request to USPS website with jquery, I have gotten it to work on my work pc, with internet explorer only for some reason. and I get a CORS error on the newer version of IE and also Firefox and Chrome.

In a question I wasn't allowed to comment on due to not having a rep, they suggested sending it to a server first then making the request instead of from the browser, Can somebody explain this to me? How can I host a server with javascript, I simply need to use this API to get tracking information and this stupid CORS restriction is a pain in my rear every time I try to do something like this.

Please help.

```
  function sendTrackingRequest(x) {
        var requestURL = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML="
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open( "GET", requestURL + trackNumberToBeTracked, true);
        // various sanitizations should be employed on the backend when dealing with user input
        request.responseType = "text/xml";
        request.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "xml" );
        request.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( request.status == 200 ) {
                    // process response
                    var trackingStatus = request.response
                    showResult(trackingStatus);
                    console.log(trackNumberToBeTracked);
                } else {
                    alert("error")
                }
            }
        }, false );
        request.send();
    }
});
```

Comment: You need a web server.

Comment: Oh thanks, could you point me somewhere that I can figure out what that means. @slaks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server

Comment: Their server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`; you shouldn't actually have a problem.  What error do you get?

Comment: `Content-Type` makes no sense on GET requests.

Comment: Thats what I am confused about, if I put the url into my browser and it works, I also was able to retrieve data using Internet Explorer at work. I get this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=%3CTrackRequest%20USERID=%22648FOOTL0638%22%3E%3CTrackID%20ID=%229405510200839104436417%22%3E%3C/TrackID%3E%3C/TrackRequest%3E. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: How would redirecting it to a server change anything? It would still be sending a request from an domain it wont recognize.

Comment: I have set up an apache webserver through xampp, How can I send a request through this server?

Comment: You need to write server-side code that receives an AJAX request from your page, then sends an HTTP request and replies with the result.

Comment: You need to understand what the Same-Origin Policy is, and why.  It only applies to browsers.

Comment: @Bluestreak22: By `request it from the server first` the person saying that meant to imply `request it from the SAME server that is serving your page`. That is: make the data come from the same domain thus completely avoiding any cross-domain issue. When you now mention you've just set up xampp I'm starting to think you don't have access to the server that is serving the page you're developing on. Are you writing a 3rd party script for someone else's website?

Comment: This is a script using api that was registered for through USPS for work. Its a simple web page with a text box that takes the tracking numbers puts it into the XML api given, and returns tracking status's. I understand same-origin policy now after reading 100 articles. But I dont understand why I am getting the error when A.I was able to retrieve the data on Internet Explorer at work, not at home. and B. Why am I getting this error if the API was specifically designed for this type of request.

Comment: Slaks your comment about Content-Type makes no sense on GET requests was right. I remove this and I get no more CORS errors. Thank you for you help. Its pretty cool that you work for google man.

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone.

Please bear with me I have made a huge beginner mistake and figured out what was wrong with Slakes help.

So in my code, I had a function with a similar name which was a .response not defined. I got this error after I listened to the first helper who said a contenttype was not necesarry for a Get request which he was right after further research.

After i removed all the bad functions which i was testing, I finally got my response to work. here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#trackButton').click(function() {
    var enteredNumber = $('#trackingNumbers').value;
    var trackNumberToBeTracked = '<TrackRequest USERID="648FOOTL0638">    <TrackID ID="9405510200839104436417"></TrackID></TrackRequest>'
    sendTrackingRequest();

    function sendTrackingRequest(x) {
        var requestURL = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML="
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open( "GET", requestURL + trackNumberToBeTracked, true);
        // various sanitizations should be employed on the backend when dealing with user input
        request.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( request.status == 200 ) {
                    // process response
                    var trackingStatus = request.response
                    alert(trackingStatus);
                    console.log(trackNumberToBeTracked);
                } else {
                    alert("error")
                }
            }
        }, false );
        request.send();
    }
});
```

Here is the code that was below it, giving me the error after I took out set header type (which solved my CORS issue as POST requests are not allowed on the api)

```
function showResult(request) {
    var xmlDoc = request.response.documentElement;
    removeWhitespace(xmlDoc);
    var outputResult = $("#BodyRows");
    var rowData = xmlDoc.$("#Employee");

    addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(rowData,outputResult);
};
```

});